# How to re-attach the phone image wrapper to an Android Emulator device which has had its data wiped

Tags: android, react-native, android-emulator

When I wiped data from the emulator the phone system image got detached, how do I re-attach it?

So far I've tried

- refreshing and reselecting the tiramisu image.
- Checking the Enable Device Frame box
- I'm rebooting the PC each time.
- I cold rebooted the avd incase that would help
- Deleting userdata-qemu.img

Answer (score 0):

Use your ANDROID_HOME environment variable which should be set to
`C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk`
This is a good way to remember the image destination.

Within the ANDROID_HOME folder there's another folder called skins. This is the folder that you hook up to your device in Android Studio

[image]
Show Advanced Settings

[image]
Scroll Down to beneath the storage section and click the three dots next to the skin dropdown

[image]
There you can provide the path to your skins folder and this will re-attach the image.